# 3d audio representation of objects on a map

Tags: audio

OK, I'm going to try to explain the issue I am having in a few lines.
I am a blind game developer, and as such I make games using only audio and not graphics, so other blind people can play.

I am trying to build a binaural audio scene in a game. However, the sounds that play only represent their center position on the screen, x/2 and y/2.

This works fine for persons, cars, and other small objects however, when there is a door or a wall, that occupies 5 squares or the whole x or y in the case of walls, I am clueless as to how to implement this into sound.

Does anyone have any ideas?
I don't think this has nothing to do with the sound library that I use, rather it's to do with maths or geometry etc.

I thought about creating multiple coppies of the sound, one for each position, but people say it's a really bad idea.

So what do you suggest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a set of audio filters which gets applied to sound of any object to indicate attributes like its size and whether its moving towards or away from POV

Experiment with defining these audio filters to be possibly modulating its volume up and down  or maybe modulating the frequency of an object's audio

These audio filters are applying an agreed upon audio texture to the object's audio